# How to hide an item in the extended menu?

Tags: windows

when I add an item in the context menu it is also added in the extended menu, is there any way to avoid that? (I just want to display it in the normal context menu, and hide it in the extended menu that is enabled by pressing SHIFT+CLICK)

Normal reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Name]
"MUIVerb"="Name"
"Icon"="\"xyz.ico\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Name\command]
@=...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static verb like you are using here will always be visible in the extended menu.

If you change to a dynamic verb and a shell extension that implements `IContextMenu` then you can check for `CMF_EXTENDEDVERBS` but doing all this work is not worth it just to hide yourself in the extended menu (IMHO).

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you very much